Distribution of a spread of observations in triplicate sample taken from Gaussian distribution
Suppose random triplicate samples are taken from a Gaussian distribution with known mean and SD. What should be the distribution of the maximum absolute difference between 3 possible pairs of observations within each sample (the range of a triplicate)?

I don't believe the pdf or cdf has a closed-form but both can be easily approximated with numerical integration.

The difference of iid Gaussian RVs is Gaussian, and the absolute value follows a folded normal distribution - since there are 3 possible nonzero pairwise differences, try working out the distribution of the max order statistic of three folded Gaussians

@RandySavage I assume you mean three non-independent folded Gaussians.  That would seem much more complicated than necessary.

@JimB, Other than Monte Carlo, is there a simpler way to estimate how scattered the triplicate samples should be if they are uncontaminated and were taken from a Gaussian parent distribution with known variance.  In other words, how far an observation in the triplicate should be from eg. the mean of the other, closer pair to suspect contamination/outlier?  I suspect that the natural spread in v. small samples may be greater than the intuition suggests even if the observations are well-behaved...

You need to specify what you want in standard statistical lingo devoid of whatever one's current "intuition" happens to be.  You now have introduced "contamination", "mean of the other, closer pair", and "natural spread" that you haven't defined.  Describing the practical/subject matter aspects of why you want the distribution of the range of 3 independent identically distributed normals would be helpful.

@JimB: In short, I'm trying to ascertain how scattered the distribution of observations within a triplicate sample should be not to reject the hypothesis that the sample was drawn at random from a parent Gaussian distribution with known variance.   The scatter within a triplicate could be measured by its range (i.e. the most distant pair of observations) or perhaps the largest distance between an observation and the mean of the other two.  Sample contamination means that the observed scatter magnitude indicates that the sample is unlikely drawn from the parent distribution assumed above.

@RandySavage: If the samples were duplicates that would be easy as the distribution of their ranges (if the parent distribution was Gaussian) should be Gaussian with mean zero and twice the variance, folded at zero.  But with triplicates there is a complication of the max of three distances.  Not sure how to do it and not sure how to use the suggestion regarding the complication of order statistics and independence (or lack thereof) in practice.

If the question is about finding the distribution of the range of sample of 3 independent observations from a common normal distribution with known mean and variance, then numerical integration will give that to you.  What you want to do with that distribution needs more clarification from you.
Suppose we have independent random variables $X_1$, $X_2$, and $X_3$ from a normal distribution with mean 0 and variance 1.  The joint density of the minimum ($X_{(1)}$) and the maximum ($X_{(3)}$) is given by
$$\frac{3 e^{-\frac{x_{(1)}^2}{2}-\frac{x_{(3)}^2}{2}} (\Phi (x_{(3)})-\Phi (x_{(1)}))}{\pi }$$
where $\Phi$ is the standard normal cumulative distribution function (cdf).  The probability density function (pdf) of the range ($X_{(3)}-X_{(1)}$) is given by
$$\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } \frac{3 e^{-\frac{x_{(1)}^2}{2}-\frac{1}{2} (x_{(1)}+z)^2} (\Phi (x_{(1)}+z)-\Phi (x_{(1)}))}{\pi } \, dx_{(1)}$$
There is no nice closed-form for this pdf but numerical integration works fine.  Here I've used Mathematica but this can be also coded in R.  (Let me know if coding this in R is necessary.)
Φ[z_] := 1 - (1 - Erf[z/Sqrt[2]])/2
Plot[NIntegrate[(3 E^(-(x1^2/2) - (z + x1)^2/2)  (-Φ[x1] + Φ[z + x1]))/π, {x1, -∞, ∞}], {z, 0, 6},
  Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {All, {0, 0.5}}, PlotRangePadding -> None,
  FrameLabel -> {"Range", "PDF"}]


Finding the cdf is just one more level of numerical integration:
Plot[NIntegrate[(3 E^(-(x^2/2) - (z + x)^2/2)  (-Φ[x] + Φ[z + x]))/π, {x, -∞, ∞}], {z, 0, 6},
  FrameLabel -> {"Range", "CDF"}]


To obtain a table of cdf values:
TableForm[
  Table[{z0, NIntegrate[(3  E^(-(x^2/2) - (z + x)^2/2)   (-Φ[ x] + Φ[z + x]))/π, {x, -∞, ∞}, {z, 0, z0}]},
  {z0, 0, 6, 0.25}], TableHeadings -> {None, {"Range", "CDF"}}]


A denser set of values can be obtained by changing the 0.25 to a much smaller value.

Thank you!  Would it be difficult to extract numerical quantiles from it using Mathematica?  And I have a question, which will probably infuriate purists: I do understand that this distribution probably has no close-form solution, but... could some other common distributions (like Beta with some parameters or maybe some others) approximate this distribution (ie. be fitted to it 'well enough' throughout the most of the range) to do away with the need for integration to derive reasonable, approximate quantiles from it?

Not difficult at all.  Essentially the Plot function is replaced with a Table function.  I'll add that later today.  Nothing wrong with using an approximating distribution but that really requires you to be more specific as to what "well enough" means.  For example, are you only interested in the upper tail region and if so, how close do you want the approximation to be?

In practice, it is indeed probably more meaningful to fit 'well enough' the upper tail as too high of a range in the triplicate sample may be indicative of the sample being 'odd' and serve as a potential warning that it's been unlikely been drawn from the assumed Gaussian distribution.  It doesn't have to be very close - but the fatness of the tail may matter - it's about not being alarmed if it is likely that the triplicate sample is spread so much and being warned that something may not have gone as planned if more. I'd think that being within a few % of the actual CDF (at the tail) is good.

That being said, it may also be 'odd' if the observations in the triplicate sample are all the same all of a sudden, but that's usually less of a problem.

Perhaps Chi-squared or F distributions, or even Log-normal could also be candidates for a reasonable approximation?

If you have some process in mind that causes the "contamination", then one could construct a targeted test statistic (although with just 3 observations nothing is going to be great).  But I'm not hearing about a contamination model from you.  The pdf and cdf for the range are easily tabulated so why you would need a proxy distribution has not been described.

The range of triplicates can serve as a rough 'blunder' detection method. I don't think that in the context of blood pressure measurements a cleaner contamination model would succeed.  This is because the BP varies, often rapidly, on the timescales of beats, minutes, hours, and even seasons and the oscillometric sphygmomanometer reports proxy values derived indirectly from waveform envelope of pulse pressure amplitudes recorded during cuff deflation which takes several seconds and uses variety of obscure proprietary algorithms.  The method is prone to occasional off.the wall values.

Fitting one of the common distributions to the the integrated PDF/CDF of the ranges (if a nice fit exists) would have the advantage of not having to use a special table of values just for this application.

From your latest comments I infer that someone takes 3 blood pressure measurements.  Is the decision to be made whether or not to take a second set of measurements based on the range of the 3 observations?  And, if so, then the second set of measurements is recorded into the patients record?  (I also assume that this process doesn't go on forever.)  If that is the case, then you just need to decide on a cut-off value in the upper tail.  No need for any approximating distributions.  (And I'm guessing that systolic and diastolic readings have two different "known" standard deviations.)

Possibly yes to all questions.  But wouldn't it be nice to have a fitted approximate closed-form distribution to either memorise just a parameter or two to easily reconstruct the table or to resample from this distribution to model it further if needed?
